# Loading into MySQL turns String to 1

Tags: mysql, sql, database

## Context:

Goal: load many '.csv' in a single MySQL table.

Input: 'Country' column has 'China' as only value.

1. csv['Country']:

   'China' = 5008

Problem: Some of this 'China's turn into '1'.

Output:

2. MySQL['Country']:

   'China' = 5000

   '1' = 8

## Question

Why is MySQL recognizing SOME strings as numbers?

## Code

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "c:\\database\\data\\motor\\bike.csv" INTO TABLE china.bike
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ","
LINES TERMINATED BY "\n"
IGNORE 1 LINES
(`col1`, `col2`, ..., `Country`);
```

Comment: that is strange as it seems that mysql makes two columns, which i have enever seen. ot will be impüossible to reproduce the problem, as you didn't specifiy which version of mysql you are using and also a sample of your data including a create table, but you can try `ENCLOSED BY '"'`

Comment: Please add table definition and sample from cvs file

Comment: Find 1-2 rows which are imported correctly, and the same but which are imported incorrectly. Provide them as CSV content sample.

Comment: Solved by @nbk, some fields had quotation and comma... Thank you.